# How to get org-mode to stop prompting me to save org-mode files that contain Babel blocks?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

When I open an org-mode file that has a babel block in emacs-lisp format, afterwards, whenever I run `save-some-buffers`, I get the `File to save in:` prompt for the current org-mode file. I get this prompt every time I run `save-some-buffers`, and each time, I have to Quit out of it.

To try to make the prompt go away I tried accepting it and saving the current file again, which had the effect of overwriting the entire org-mode file with just the first emacs-lisp block.

How do I get org-mode to stop prompting me to save org files that contain Babel blocks?

Comment: As indicated in a previous thread, you need someone to help you write the second argument (a custom function) to `save-some-buffers` to provide you with custom exclusions -- based on perhaps major-mode and/or buffer-name and/or some other criteria that suits your personal needs.  You are using `t` for the second *optional* argument to `save-some-buffers`, and when `t` is set for that second argument -- i.e., `PRED` -- it tries to save certain non-file-visiting-buffers and also file-visiting-buffers.  See the doc-string for `save-some-buffers` for more details.

Comment: This only happens when I run org-babel. I am successfully able to exclude other buffer types from save-some-buffers (e.g. grep buffers, helm buffers, etc) that save-some-buffers by default prompts me to save.

Comment: Sorry, my apologies.  It is the first argument for this particular question:  "*This command first saves any buffers where `buffer-save-without-query` is non-nil, without asking.  Optional argument (the prefix) non-nil means save all with no questions.*"  So take a look at the value for `buffer-save-without-query` and make a decision whether you want the first *optional* argument to `save-some-buffers` set to `t`.  You could also use `C-u` to set the first argument each time you call `save-some-buffers`.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your issue. Would you provide some additional details such as your emacs version and org-mode version and a short org-mode file example that can be used for troubleshooting, please?